# Android WebView not loading HTML file

Tags: android, html, webview

I created a HTML file and added it to the assets folder. I added a webview to an axml file like so

```
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:id="@+id/LocalWebView">
</WebView>
```

and tried loading it with the following code

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Teams);

            WebView localWebView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.LocalWebView);
            localWebView.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/Content/Teams.html");
        }
```

It tells me the file was not found. Is there somewhere other than the assets folder I have to add the html page or something else I have to do?

Comment: Are you sure that your file is where you think it is, within `assets/`, of your project?

Comment: Yes and the only other file in there is "aboutassets". Should that be right?

Comment: `Is there somewhere other than the assets folder I have to add the html page`. You should add it to the 'Content' folder in assets.

Comment: I have the content folder in as well

Comment: I have a warning on the "WebView" element on the axml that it is not declared but on the activity page it still finds it id. Would it be anything to do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have "Content" folder inside your asset and the HTML page inside the Content folder if that is correct then rebuild your app and then run. If again it will generate error then comment the exact error name that occurs.

Comment: The error message is Webpage not available. The webpage at "file///android_asset/Content/Teams.html cannot be loaded because net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Answer (score 0):

**put these lines too**

```
 WebView webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_view1);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/about_us.html");
```

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, how these would prevent a file-not-found error in the `WebView`.

Comment: It won't prevent from file not found error. It just enables javascript and zoom control and enhance the smoothness of WebView

Comment: add that in the answer not as comment

Answer (score 0):

In my case, rebuilding the solution simply fixed the issue.
Actually it could load only one URL and refused to load the others which was totally odd so I decided to rebuild the solution. There is another thing. Putting the `html` files inside the `Content` folder ***is not*** an obligation.

Please notice that I am using `xamarin` framework and `visual studio` as the IDE. 
I hope it helps.